# How to fix "Could not deduce (Num (Sum a)) arising from a use of ‘+’"?

Tags: haskell

I took code from [this lecture](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/07-folds-monoids.html), but I got an error with the demo code below:

```
newtype Sum a = Sum a
  deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
getSum::Sum a -> a
getSum (Sum a) = a
instance Num a=>Monoid (Sum a)where
  mempty = Sum 0
  mappend = (+)
newtype  Product a = Product a
  deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
getProduct ::Product a -> a
getProduct (Product a ) = a
instance Num a => Monoid (Product a ) where
  mempty = Product 1
  mappend = (*)
```

I got the following error message (with GHC 8.2.2):

```
Test.hs:40:13: error:
       ? Could not deduce (Num (Sum a)) arising from a use of ‘+’
         from the context: Num a
           bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:38:10-30
       ? In the expression: (+)
         In an equation for ‘mappend’: mappend = (+)
         In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid (Sum a)’   
 | 40 |   mappend = (+)  

Test.hs:50:13: error:
    ? Could not deduce (Num (Product a)) arising from a use of ‘*’
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:48:10-37
    ? In the expression: (*)
      In an equation for ‘mappend’: mappend = (*)
      In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid (Product a)’
50 |   mappend = (*)
```

Comment: You didn't copy it accurately.

Comment: (1) "You didn't copy it accurately" -- More specifically, the code in the lecture does derive `Num` for `Sum` and `Product`. (2) GitHub style fenced code blocks (delimited by \`\`\`) don't work here. (3) @Nayantara Jeyaraj It is better to format error messages as code, to preserve formatting and avoid things like \* being parsed as Markdown. You can add blockquote formatting around the code block if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining `mappend` as `(+)`, you're saying that `Sum a` is itself a member of `Num`. Rather, it only contains those members, so `(+)` should operate on those members.

```
instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a) where
    mempty                  = Sum 0
    mappend (Sum x) (Sum y) = Sum $ x + y
```

Likewise for `Product`

```
instance Num a => Monoid (Product a) where
    mempty                          = Product 1
    mappend (Product x) (Product y) = Product $ x * y
```

Then your monoid instances work as expected.

```
xs = map Sum [1..5]
ys = map Product [1..5]
mconcat xs  -- 15
mconcat ys  -- 120
```

---

Alternatively you could follow the lecture's code and derive `Num` in your newtypes.

```
-- from the linked lecture
newtype Sum a = Sum a
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Num, Show)
newtype Product a = Product a
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Num, Show)
```

Comment: Yes , I delete deriving Num from code ,beacause it raise  derive error,and now  I find solution to aovid this . enable the GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving extension as GHCi suggests. thks